# pass the controller fetched value in blade file to query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have fetch ed the controller value in blade file as `{{ $user->user_name }}`.I want to pass the value to query in same blade file .

```
sample.blade.php
{{$user->user_name}}

$test=db::table('department')->where('department.parent_department','=','{{ $user->user_name }}')->get();
```

Comment: views are not good place for queries. that said, you should remove the braquet since you are in php block

Answer (score 0):

you can just use it like this, no need that curly braces.

```
$test=DB::table('department')->where('department.parent_department','=',$user->user_name)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `{{ }}` around the variable

```
$test = DB::table('department')
    ->where('department.parent_department','=', $user->user_name)
    ->get();
```

of course, views are not a good place for writing your queries. Instead, try to put it in controllers

Answer (score 0):

Remove these {{}} and no need of 'department.parent_department''parent_department' it will work too

```
$test = DB::table('department')
    ->where('parent_department','=', $user->user_name)
    ->get();
```

hope this will help you one more thing only in view {{}} use

Comment: And no need for '=' too.